# Does anyone know how many garble between in the following sentence?

Tags: american-english

Does anyone know how many garble between in the following sentence?
The original sentence is here.
 "Attached is the latest version of our poster for ready to be released."

And I did rephrase one like this 
"The latest attachment of our post is ready for release."

But someone did tell me about my sentence was garble.
so I don't have idea which point is exactly garble do in my sentence?

Comment: Are you looking for the definition of *garble*? From [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/garble): *to cause (a word, name, message, etc.) to be unclear or confusing*.

Comment: If the good part of the original sentence was attached to the good part of your sentence, we would have a good sentence. `Attached is the latest version of our poster, which is ready for release.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the original (with a small correction):

> **Attached** is the latest version of our poster (that is) ready to be released.

*attached* is a verb. This is an action to put together something with something else. The meaning here is that the poster is attached to something (perhaps to an email?)

But in your phrase:

> The latest **attachment** of our post(er) is ready for release.

*attachment* is a noun. This is a thing that is attached. The meaning here is that something attached to the poster (the attachment) is ready for release.

Both are valid statements but the meanings are different.